# Efficient operation on rows in python pandas.Series object

Tags: python, pandas, time

I want to calculate multiple features based on one column in my `pandas.Dataframe` containing alphanumeric strings.

I want do calculate new values based on each of these strings, such as ratio of alphabetic, numeric, vowel and consonant characters. Because I have 100's of millions of strings, I want to find the most efficient way to calculate these values.

Currently I am calculating it in the following way for my `pandas.DataFrame` df and the column `domain`:

```
alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
fn = lambda row: sum(row.domain.count(a) for a in alphabet) / len(row.domain)
df.assign(alphabetic_ratio=df.apply(fn, axis=1).values)
```

Currently I am following the same scheme for numeric, vowel and consonant ratios, but because of the number of string it takes so long to calculate (alphabetic ratio 6+ hours).

I am not sure if I am doing anything obviously wrong to explain why it takes so much time, or if there are any tricks that can be implemented to speed up the calculations.

I know that converting the code to `C` and using `cython` *might* improve the time, but I want to first explore real pythonic solutions. If anyone can tell me that it definitely will improve the time scale, I will try it out.

I tried other methods to determine if a character is alphabetic, such as checking the `ord(a)` number or `a.isalpha()', but the time is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example helps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['John', 'Michael', 'Jezus', 'Donald', 'Suzy']})

df['B'] = df.A.str.count('[a-z]') / df.A.str.len()

df
#         A         B
#0     John  0.750000
#1  Michael  0.857143
#2    Jezus  0.800000
#3   Donald  0.833333
#4     Suzy  0.750000
```

As from your example it seems you only look at the `domain` column that is same as `A` in this example.